# How to get the frame of a view inside another view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, frame

I have an `UIImageView` in the `self.view` (the main View) and inside it there is a `UIButton`. I want to know what's the frame of `UIButton` in `self.view` not in `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this method

[– convertRect:toView:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622504-convert)

```
// Swift
let frame = imageView.convert(button.frame, to: self.view)

// Objective-C
CGRect frame = [imageView convertRect:button.frame toView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 21):

There are four `UIView` methods which can help you, converting `CGPoints` and `CGRects` from one `UIView` coordinate reference to another:

```
– convertPoint:toView:
– convertPoint:fromView:
– convertRect:toView:
– convertRect:fromView:
```

so you can try

```
CGRect f = [imageView convertRect:button.frame toView:self.view];
```

or

```
CGRect f = [self.view convertRect:button.frame fromView:imageView];
```

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 3**

You can convert the button's frame to the view's coordinate system with this:

`self.view.convert(myButton.frame, from: myButton.superview)`

---

Make sure to put your logic inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and not `viewDidLoad`. Geometry related operations should be performed after subviews are laid out, otherwise they may not work properly.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let buttonFrame = self.view.convert(myButton.frame, from: myButton.superview)
    }
}
```

You can just reference `myButton.superview` instead of `myImageView` when converting the frame.

---

Here are more options for converting a `CGPoint` or `CGRect`.

```
self.view.convert(point: CGPoint, from: UICoordinateSpace)
self.view.convert(point: CGPoint, from: UIView)             
self.view.convert(rect: CGRect, from: UICoordinateSpace)
self.view.convert(rect: CGRect, from: UIView)

self.view.convert(point: CGPoint, to: UICoordinateSpace)
self.view.convert(point: CGPoint, to: UIView)
self.view.convert(rect: CGRect, to: UICoordinateSpace)
self.view.convert(rect: CGRect, to: UIView)
```

---

See the [Apple Developer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertRect:toView:) for more on converting a `CGPoint` or `CGRect`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? might be totally wrong, dint really thinkt it through ;p

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.origin.x-imageview.frame.origin.x) +btn.frame.origin.x,
                          (self.view.frame.origin.y.imageview.frame.origin.y)+btn.frame.origin.y,
                          btn.frame.size.width,
                          btn.frame.size.height);
```

I don't know if theres any easier way.