# iOS: How to Detect subview position around view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel, uitouch

I have a Label named "`Lable_Match`" (in self.view)

 and a `UIView`(in self.view).
 In that View there are 1000+ labels.

 and view is move using touch move method. and When user move View and he touch end that time check view subview lable is on the "`Lable_Match`" if any one lable is on this so the check text are same or not.

Comment: Some People are Down vote Without giving any Reason.

Comment: is it a uitableview or view?
how are you doing this?
1000+ in a view?
that is causing ambiguity,
I have not downwoted you post atleast.
Please clarify, so that i  may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to use this method:
    [self.view convertRect:self.label.frame fromView:self.view.subview];

from this post: [How to get the frame of a view inside another view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082493/how-to-get-the-frame-of-a-view-inside-another-view)

This will give you the adjusted position of the label form your list of 1000+ labels. You can then compare that to the label of Label_match , then compare their text

Comment: i will check and give response as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks i Get position according to self.view for usgin             CGRect frame = [subview convertRect:self.view.frame toView:self.view];

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question my question is there any way to find the location of your label. If you have the fixed location for label then you can match current taped area and the label area and find the text. Or if you have a fixed sized label you can manipulate it and able to get the label text

Comment: There is no taped(no click event). Only Touch move

Comment: -(void)moveViewWithGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
}

Comment: not only that you can easily avail the label from the gesture by below code:    'UILabel * label = (UILabel *)[panGestureRecognizer view];'