# Getting Frame from Nested UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, autolayout, cgrect

I have a `UIButton` that is nested within 2 `UIStackView`s that are nested within a `UIView`.

[image]

I give it constraints, however, when I

`print(helloButton.frame)`

the `CGRect` output has different values than what appears on the screen.

Notably the coordinates are off.

Is there a reason for this? How do I accurately get the `UIButton` frame?

Comment: Do you get a warning on your layout about being unable to satisfy constraints?

Comment: @Ares I added a picture, check it out. It is easily reproducible

Comment: When in the lifecycle are you printing the frame?

Comment: @Ares `viewDidAppear`. I also tried with another `UIButton`. same thing

Comment: See the Yellow Right Arrow right next to  "View Controller Scene"? If you click it it will show a list of warnings about your layout.

Comment: @Ares That wasn't the problem. Edited

Comment: What coordinates are you expecting? What makes you think they're "off"?

Comment: @Ares the answer is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082493/how-to-get-the-frame-of-a-view-inside-another-view

Comment: @beyowulf the answer is above

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question. The coordinate origin of a `UIView.frame` CGRect at any time is based on the origin of its containing `UIView`, not that of the application's view.

To obtain its coordinates based on the origin of the application (absolute top-left corner) I did this:

In Swift:

```
let absoluteFrame = myView.convertRect(myView.frame, toView: nil)
```

Comment: You also should make this conversion in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, not in `viewDidAppear` (layout may not have finished in `viewDidAppear`)