# How to get the position of rightBarButtonItems of navigationItem?

Tags: swift

I have an array of navigation items. I am trying to add a popover near one of the navigation items. I am not using CustomView in the button

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [infoBarButtonItem, aboutBarButtonItem]

let barButtonView = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.first
```

How can I get the CGPoints of barButtonView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to get at private data. Before iOS 11, it's possible to get the view of UIBarButtonItem with `value(forKey:)` func but it no longer gives you the view. As far as I know, the only way is to make a bar button item with a custom view and just keep a reference to that custom view so you can get its position later. There's also a similar thread on the Apple developer forum so I'll attach the link in case you're curious. [Apple Developer Forum Thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/87823) There was also a similar question on StackOverflow nine years ago.[Old StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082493/how-to-get-the-frame-of-a-view-inside-another-view)